# Why is my array going out of bounds?

Tags: java, arrays, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to access the next element of the array but it says I'm out of bounds.

```
private void board(Scanner file) {
    String[][] board = new String[r][c]; //r=25 c=75
    int col = 0;
    for(int row = 0; file.hasNextLine() && row<r ; row++){
        board[row]=file.nextLine().split("");
        neighbors(board,row,col);
        col++;
        System.out.println(file.next());
    }

}

private void neighbors(String[][] board, int row, int col) {
    if(col<c && "X".equals(board[row][col+1])){//right
        neighbors++;
        System.out.println(neighbors);
    }

}
```

Comment: *Where* are you going out of bounds?

Comment: my neighbors method, when i check for a neighbor to the right

Comment: What if your col has no neighbour on the right? Have you thought about this?

Answer (score 0):

In the line `if(col<c && "X".equals(board[row][col+1])){`, you first ensure that `col` is less than the number of columns in your array, but then you try to dereference the array at `col+1`.  If `col` is already `c-1`, then `col+1` is an invalid array index, which will result in an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` being thrown.

Comment: okay i think i understand, so I would want to find the col value then compare it  so it's not getting compared twice?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with how many times you're using `col`.  You're checking that `col` is in bounds -- fine.  But you're not using using `col` as an array index; you're using `col+1`.  And even if `col` is in bounds, `col+1` may not be.  You probably want to verify that `c != 0 && col < c-1`

Comment: i know c !=0, its final at 75.

Answer (score 0):

`board[row]=file.nextLine().split("");`
this line will make new array "of any length depending on the line returned by `file.nextLine()` and the `split()` " so the `board[row]` now refer to array that its length could be not equal to c , i think your `split("")` will return array of size 1

so instead of comparing `col < c` use `col < board[row].length ;`
also reconsider your `split("")` for example if the line are 1 2 3
you can use `split(" ");`

Comment: im splitting at .X, which is why I chose "" because it isn't a space. So would this be incorrect?

Comment: for example first row may be .............................xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.x.x.x.x.x.x.xxxxx.x.x.x.x etc.

Comment: in the example you give what are the elements you expect from split() is it {xxxxxxxxxx  ,  x  ,  x  ,  x  ,  x  ,  x  ,  x  ,  xxxxx  ,  x  , .......etc } if so you should use `split(".") ;`

Comment: I may think you need array of characters that make up the line, if so you can't use split("") for this purpose instead use `file.nextLine().toCharArray();` and change the array type to char array